# IIS Rest Api - Put And Delete requests are not working ERR_FAILED 403

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, web-hosting, http-status-code-403

I've deployed asp.net core web api app to contabo vps server and I've realized that HTTP PUT requests are not working at all.

Every single HTTP PUT or HTTP DELETE requests displays same message:

> PUT https://my-domain.plesk.page/api/categories/1
> net::ERR_FAILED 403

What I've tried is I've uninstalled WebDAV from IIS.
But issue is still here.

I've tried also editing web.config file and it looks like this:

```
 <system.webServer>
        <modules>
         <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
       <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyDemoApp.API.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="outofprocess" />
</system.webServer>
```

Any kind of help would be awesome

Thanks guys!

Cheers

Comment: If removing `WebDAVModule` from `modules` and `handlers` doesn't resolve your problem in that case could please try like `1. go to IIS manager` then `2.Right click on your app` `3.Edit Permission` `4.Select Security` `5. Select CREATOR OWNER ` `6.Edit` `7. Check Full Control`  `9. Click OK` `10. Restart your app in IIS`. You could try this steps. Let us know your feedback hows going on.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in `<system.webServer>`

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
```

Also, you can try like:-

```
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" 
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Tried all of that. Nothing worked.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Sending a PUT request from Insomnia works ok, but using Angular's HttpClient fails with 403 status code.